# Copy range based on dropdown

Tags: excel, vba, dropdown, copy-paste, lookup

A dropdown populates `B2` of `Sheet1` with a value. I need to find this value in `Sheet2`, and copy a range starting from that cell, to **5 columns right** and **18 rows down**. This value copied range is always pasted to `I3:M20`.

For example, if the value from the dropdown is found in `A75` then range `A75:E92` should be copied to `I3:M20`.

Thanks.

Comment: Please post the code you have to this point.  also this can be done easily with native formula.

Comment: I have no code at this point. I couldn't figure out how to perform a vlookup while recording a macro.

Comment: Please share with us the code involved with "a dropdown populates ...".  The dropdown seems to be able of populating B2, or A75 (or probably many cells -- Which cells?).  One solution might be "Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)" but then how would the sub know that the change arose from a dropdown rather than from some manual entry?

Comment: @donPablo It sounds to me like the dropdown populates B2 on Sheet1 only. In the example given, that value was found in A75 on Sheet2, not populated by the dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to happen automatically when the value changed you need to use `Sub Worksheet_Change` as mentioned by @donPablo in the comments. Verify that the cell that was changed was the cell of interest, then find the value from `B2` on `Sheet2`. You can use `Resize` to get the larger area you're interested, and then copy it where you want it.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Target.Address = "$B$2" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim ToFind
    Dim Found
    ToFind = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value
    Set Found = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1", "E300").Find(ToFind, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not Found Is Nothing Then
        Found.Resize(18, 5).Copy
        Sheets("Sheet2").Range("I3").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    End If
End Sub
```